# Why does MS Teams card action openUrl() on OS X fail to bring the browser into the fore ground?

Tags: macos, microsoft-teams

I have an MS Teams app with an adaptive card  on which there is a button that performs an OpenURL().

The URL is opened correctly but on OS X MS Teams remains in the foreground hiding the browser.
On windows it works as expected: the URL is opened in the browser and the browser is moved to the foreground.

It doesn't seem to matter what the default browser is or what page I open.

Answer (score 0):

I have informed this issue to internal team. Can you also provide the feedback/Report an issue on Teams app. Go to settings -> Help & Feedback.

Comment: It looks like this has been fixed now.